# Monaco Locale Suggestion intellisense disabling

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

Change the keyboard language to other language( in my case it is Japanese using alt + shift),
and start typing in Monaco editor, it is showing some intellisense menu with remove and search option.

Version of Monaco Editior: V0.33.0

[image]

For my case I have to hide the Locale intellisense Menu.

Answer (score 1):

That's just Windows' [input method editor (IME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) for Japanese.

You get it when you install [the Japanese IME](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-japanese-ime-da40471d-6b91-4042-ae8b-713a96476916) / Japanese [Language Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs-for-windows-a5094319-a92d-18de-5b53-1cfc697cfca8). You'll probably see that same IME window in any text input you type in in any application.

Instructions on how to install a language pack can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-a-language-for-windows-ccd853d3-9ecd-7da7-9ef0-72b4a055410a).